# There has to be vs there have to be

Tags: singular-vs-plural

What's correct here?

> There **has** to be some people left after the flood.
>
> There **have** to be some people left after the flood.

I assume "have" because "people" is plural but I'm confused now because I was told that some people is uncountable, so that would make it come with the singular verb tense.

Comment: You are perfectly correct. Can you explain your confusion so that we may better help you?

Comment: Well I was told that some people is uncountable, so that would make it come with the singular verb tense.

Answer (score 4):

People is a plural noun; it's used as the plural of 'person'. You use the plural form of a verb after it. So the correct sentence is:

There have to be some people left after the flood.

Comment: +1 but good to note that the plural of 'person' can be 'persons' as well! :)

Comment: Maulik, My dear, you are right. What an upvote on an answer that was halwa!

Comment: I was in mood to upvote...that's it.. and there's nothing wrong in upvoting a 'right' answer! :) It just happened that way! This answer can be further improved explaining the difference between 'plural' and 'uncountable' which seems a real confusion to the OP!

Answer (score 0):

'People' is indeed uncountable - there's no way of saying if it's 5, 10, or 3.1415 persons. However, it is a plural, so we're assuming that a count of those left after the flood (if it was done) would be more than one.

Therefore, it doesn't matter what the exact number is. As long as we're assuming more than one person was left, you use 'have'.